# Install and run Python 3 at the same time than Python 2

Tags: software-installation, python3

Im using 13.04 but I want have installed the both main Python versions for make tests about migration of my actual code.

is possible install Python 3 in the same machine running Python 2.7? I need work with both versions,thanks!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yes, you just need to install `python3` package.

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3
```

Python 2.X will still be the default Python used, so if you want to run a script with Python 3.X you need to run

```
$ python3 /path/to/script.py
```

or add in the first line of your executable script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Comment: I search a lot and only found information about how to install Python 3 but nothing about if my dev environment is safe with both versions running. Thanks!

Comment: @mlacunza If you install both from the default repositories (ex: with `apt-get`, Software Center) you will have no problem at all. But if you install from source, depending on where it ends installed and if it replaces the default python installation you can have some problems.

Comment: @mlacunza If this answered your question, mark it as answered.

Comment: Which version of python will be installed? In my case it installed 3.2 but I needed 3.5.