# How to install Python 3.4 on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, python3

If I open Terminal and type in python, I see the version is 2.7.4. How do I get python 3.4? And do I need IDLE if I have sublime text?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/350751/ubuntu-13-04-install-and-running-python-3-at-the-same-time-than-python-2-7-x

Comment: @don.joey: No, it's not a duplicate as 14.04 already has python 3.4 installed by default.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch I thought 13.04 also came with python 3 installed by default.

Comment: What is the use of having a old version of python.. Is there a way to uninstall the old one and make the new as default.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

python 3.4 is installed on the stable release of Ubuntu 14.04. You need to use `python3` to use python 3.4. For example, to execute a script `file.py`, use:

```
python3 file.py
```

This will use python 3.4 to interpret your program or you can use the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) to make it executable. The first line of your program should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

and then use `chmod +x file.py` to assign executable permissions and then run your python script as `./file.py` which would use python3 to execute.

If you want python3 to be used when you type python on the terminal, you can use an alias. To add a new alias, open your `~/.bash_aliases` file using `gedit ~/.bash_aliases` and type the following:

```
alias python=python3
```

and then save and exit and type

```
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

and then you can type

```
python file.py
```

to use python3 as your default python interpreter.

No, you don't need IDLE just to use python3 to interpret your programs.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to avoid typing "~/Dropbox/XXX/Pythonfiles/examplefile.py" when I want to interpret a Pythonfile (for instance "examplefile.py"?

Comment: BTW: I couldn't find the .bash_aliases file in my file manager.

Comment: 1) You can just go that directory(`~/Dropbox/XXX/Pythonfiles/`) first and then type `python examplefile.py`(this might be pretty dumb and not what you expected). 2) You could alias `python ~/Dropbox/XXX/Pythonfiles/examplefile.py` as a whole to a command which would execute when you type in the custom aliased command. 3) You won't find if you didn' have any aliases before, that is absolutely fine, you can create one.

Comment: What's the command to create this .bash_aliases file in terminal?

Comment: Thanks this worked. Is chmod +x file.py for all files or do you mean the individual pythonfile?

Comment: @user262849: Only for the individual file.

Comment: Instead of `#!/usr/bin/python3` it should be `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, for greater flexibility

Comment: I would definitely never ever set python=python3.  That would break everyyyyyything on your OS that runs on python 2.7, etc

Comment: @empedokles to create this .bash_aliases file in terminal, enter `sh -c "echo 'alias python=python3' >> ~/.bash_aliases"`

Answer (score 21):

Python 3 is installed by default on modern versions of Ubuntu, so you should already have it installed:

```
python3 -V
```

To install idle 3:

```
sudo apt-get install idle-python3.4
```

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue with my ubuntu desktop.  My python book told me to call python by just typing python in the terminal but it was only calling the previous python version 2.

1. First check if you have python version 3 or not.  Open command terminal, type

> python3

Do you see the acknowledgment that you do?  done.

2. If you don't; install using following command line.

> sudo apt-get install python3

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

On Ubuntu 14.04 Python 3.4 is installed by default.

As recommended by [PEP-394](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) you can use `python` and `python2` to run Python v2 (2.7) and `python3` to run Python v3 (3.4).

Comment: how to make python 3.4 default for Netbeans IDE ? now it is 2.7.6 when I click auto detect it will not 3.4.1 not detecting in python platform manager(Netbeans IDE 8.0.1)

Answer (score 2):

In the terminal type: `python3`

The terminal will itself say to type:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-minimal
```

Do it and this will install Python 3.2.3.

Then in the terminal type: `python3.4` -- you shall enter Python 3.4.1.

Comment: it just installs python 3.2.3 , python3.4: command not found.

Answer (score 2):

If needed for only one script, you can use an alias locally and temporarily.

When installing [**Letsencrypt**](https://letsencrypt.org/), I got the following warning :

```
$ ./letsencrypt-auto --help 

InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

The cause: Python 2.7.9 was needed, while 2.7.5 was installed. Python 3 works as well. I opened the script and inserted the following alias after the shebang:

```
alias python=python3
```

Then the script worked. When it all finished this alias was removed. It only worked in this script. So starting `python` from the terminal still got me version 2.7.5.

Answer (score 2):

#### Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and above

Since Ubuntu 18.04 and beyond, you don't have to install Python 3, as it comes by default.

> For Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Debian Buster, we want to transition to Python 3.6 as the default (and probably only) Python 3 version.

References:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python/Python36Transition

---

Otherwise install by the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

Then to locate multiple Python installations, run one of these commands:

```
whereis python
which -a python python2 python3
locate python
```

or just type `python` command and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice.

To list installed Python packages, run: `dpkg -l | grep -w python`.

To install a specific version, see: [How to install specific Ubuntu packages, with exact version?](https://askubuntu.com/q/92019/78223)

Comment: Good, this gives me python 3.6. Also there's python3.7 in repos available; however, I need to test a package against **3.4** specifically. Any hassle-free options?

Comment: @ulidtko See: [How to install specific Ubuntu packages, with exact version?](https://askubuntu.com/q/92019/78223)

Answer (score 1):

Python3.4 is already installed on your system, you just need to call it with `python3` instead of `python`

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of legacy python apps out there and thus the need for python 2.x , however as others mentioned  python3 -V shows Python 3.4.0 is installed and thus with Ubuntu 14.x it is there.

```
 python -V     shows   2.7.6

 python3 -V    shows   3.4.0
```

Knowing which interpreter to use then is up to you.