# Symbolic links: why are they so bad?

Tags: python, symbolic-link

Why is using symbolic links to change the default python version on Ubuntu considered as being unsafe ?

I read this information on several forums but did not find an answer as to why is this so.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In most systems, `python` refers to python2 and `python3` refers to python3.

The reason a symbolic link created with `python` to refer to `python3` is considered unsafe is because this will cause applications that used `python` to refer to `python2`  to crash or misbehave. This is mainly because python3 is not backward compatible with python2; [they are very much different in syntax as well as semantics](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3).

You should rather [use aliases as a better alternative to use python to refer to python3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449555/how-to-install-python-3-4-on-ubuntu-14-04/449558#449558).

symbolic links in general are not bad, it depends how you use them.

Answer (score 1):

It's not good to change the default `python` , because many programs use `python 2` rather than `python 3`. Why don't you just use the `python3` command when you need it without making any changes .

Comment: Errrr..... `paython`? (Three times as well) :)

Comment: @Wilf sadly no more!
Also see https://github.com/abunsen/Paython