# What to learn Ubuntu application development in python, where to start?

Tags: application-development, python, gui, python3

I know basic python and i love it.
I want to learn how to develop and publish Ubuntu applications in python but don't know where to start (I mean "the standard ways" to do so).
It would be good if you can also suggest best GUI toolkit to learn.
I would prefer you to answer in the perspective of python-3.4.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Developing applications in Linux isn't really a distro-specific endeavor. Your software, once built, just needs to be packaged for the distros you care about (RPMs for distros that use yum, debs for distros that use apt, or just wheels via PIP). Unless you're pulling in strange dependencies (which you should avoid anyway), you will not need to do any extra work.

There are tons of StackExchange threads on the merits of various GUI toolkits for Python. I will not duplicate that information here.

- [Is Python any good for GUI development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115495/is-python-any-good-for-gui-development)
- [Python - Best GUI library for the job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743572/python-best-gui-library-for-the-job)
- [Which Python GUI library is easiest to use?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35770/which-python-gui-library-is-easiest-to-use)

Python 3.4 is standard with Ubuntu 14.04, so simple applications will use it by default with a `#!/usr/bin/env python3` shebang. More complex applications can be developed under Python 3.4 using virtualenv and/or virtualenvwrapper, then deployed with Python 3.4 via `requirements.txt` or similar.

Comment: AFAIK, Python 2.7 is still default in 14.04.

Comment: According to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449555/how-to-install-python-3-4-on-ubuntu) AskUbuntu answer, 3.4 is installed by default. I don't have an Ubuntu install handy to test against, unfortunately. Your comment did remind me that the shebang would need to be `python3` though, thanks (answer edited).

Answer (score 1):

The traditional way to make a GUI using python is [Tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter), How ever there are a lot of libraries which listed here https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming