# Will installing Python 3.2 from software center replace the original Python 2.7 on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, python

Will installing Python 3.2 from the software center  replace the default Python 2.7 on 12.04?

I would like to keep using Python 2.7, because I am afraid Python 3.2 will not recognize code written for 2.7. Thanks.

Btw, what is the default Python version in 14.04? I wonder if it is worth to upgrade my Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will installing Python 3.2 from the software center replace the default Python 2.7 on 12.04?

No, it won't.

Installing python 3.2 on 12.04 will not replace the python 2.7 already present. All applications using python 2.7 will continue to work and you can you use python 3.2 for whatever applications you want to run using

```
python3 filename
```

However, do not mess with the binary files, like replacing `/usr/bin/python` with `/usr/bin/python3` or anything.

If you just want `python` to refer to `python3` in your 12.04, [just create aliases](https://askubuntu.com/a/449558/72576). This will safely prevent applications from misbehaving and/or crashing.

> Btw, what is the default Python version in 14.04?

The default python version in 14.04 is python 2.7, although python 3.2 comes pre-installed. By default version, I mean, `python` refers to python 2.7.6.

Comment: thanks. If I have both python 3.2 and python 2.7 installed, when I install some python libraries, do I have to install two copies, each for each Python version?

Comment: @Tim: yes, you will have to install the libraries for both individually.