# Installing python 3.x on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: apt, python, python3

I have already python 2.7 on my machine. I can't recall if I installed it or it is a built-in install. Anyhow, I would like to install work with python 3.x and I wonder if I need first to uninstall the 2.7 version. Are there any component in the system which rely on this version?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't remove 2.7!! It will break your system. What is your Ubuntu version? If it is later than 12.04, python 3 is slready installed (additionally), not instead of).

Comment: The latest - 15.10

Comment: when I run "python" on terminal it uses the 2.7 version.

Comment: Wait, I will post an answer :)

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/449555/how-to-install-python-3-4-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Don't remove python 2!!

Ubuntu versions, later then 12.04 already have python 3 installed. This is an *additional* version, not *instead of*.

A lot of software (still) depends however on 2.7, removing it will break the system. On Ubuntu, `python 2` is called by:

```
python
```

or

```
python2
```

while `python 3` is called by

```
python3
```

#### See the current version(s)

If you run:

```
python3 -V
```

you will get your current version of `python 3`, while

```
python -V
```

will output the current version of `python 2`