# How do I uninstall python2.7 on 15.10?

Tags: python, 15.10, uninstall, python3

I have 2 versions of python installed on my computer, not using pythonbrew but as 2 seperate packages (2.7 as python and 3.5 as python3), I'd like to remove 2.7 and reinstall 3.5 because this causes some problems with installing modules. Any advice? And do go easy on me please :)

Comment: DON'T uninstall 2.7. Your system will break, since a lot of applications depend on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing python 3.x on Ubuntu 15.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/727476/installing-python-3-x-on-ubuntu-15-10)

Comment: Oh I had no idea, thanks. Any idea what to do regarding the modules problem? Whenever I try to install one it usually works for 2.7 instead of 3.5 (which I mainly use) even when I specify it in the installation

Comment: Which modules? In most cases, there are specific versions for specific python versions

Comment: Zlib and pip for example are preinstalled for 2.7 and I see their files in the 3.5 directory but I get import errors trying to import them

Comment: You should use the `pip3` command for your Python 3 installation. You might have to install it first with `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` . To avoid confusion, most tools have a 2 and 3 suffix. So you can use `pip2` or `pip3` to make it clear for which Python version you're installing.